# Let's fill the empty tag wiki excerpts

Tags: discussion, tags

Tags are very useful, especially if they have a tag wiki excerpt, i.e. a short description of the tag's scope. However, at the time of writing, our site appears to have dozens of tags with empty tag wiki excerpts or empty tag wikis.

You can [run this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/french/query/1250524/most-common-tags-with-short-long-or-missing-excerpt-or-wiki) to find all tags with an empty tag wiki excerpt, an empty tag wiki or both.

Let us at least fill in the empty tag wiki excerpts, since these are the texts that become visible on hover (e.g. when adding tags to a question). Based on the meta post [Style to be used in tag wikis' summaries?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/160/11052), the format for the tag wiki excerpts should be as follows:

> French description / English description.

So let's start doing this :-)

**PS**: This post was inspired by [Fill the empty tag excerpts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10144/89356) on Science Fiction and Fantasy. The query was forked from the query in that meta question.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: after checking, it appears that when you write an English tag while asking a question, the French version is directly displayed because it's marked as a synonym. Therefore, I changed my suggestion.**

If I can make a small suggestion, [the post that you linked](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/160/11052) is from a time when tags were only in one language. Today, for each French tag, we have (or should have) its equivalent in English. Therefore I suggest that we handle descriptions the following way:

> French tag or bilingual tag = French/English description.
>
> English tag = English description (optional but not very useful).

Comment: If we use tag synonyms to redirect from English tags to their French equivalents, do we still need to fill in English tag wiki excerpts?

Comment: Maybe not, now that I have the information that the tag is directly written in its French version when you try to write the English one.